# How to color data series point inside plot graph depending on data value in Excel table

Tags: excel, macos

On a data/line plot inside Excel, I'd like to color my data points depending on a value inside the table on the same row as the data value, however from a different column.

It's best explained with a picture:

[image: image.png]

It's essentially a line chart type with the lines removed, and the data points set to bullet type and given an increased radius for visibility. The x-axis denotes the calendar date as dd.mm, and the y-axis contains the values.

Now the Excel table also contains a row called "Time of Day", which can be mo(rning), mi(dday), ev(ening).

Can something like this be done with a line chart, or do I need to use a different type of chart, or is this generally not possible in Excel (which I doubt)?

Excel in use is: Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.51 (21071101).

Comment: This could be done with a macro. You are looking for `.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor` in your chart object where `x` is the number of the point you wish to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve this:

[image]

What I've done is:

- Added three columns for the times of day (columns B, C and D). These can be hidden.
- Added this formula in B2: `=IF($E2=B$1,$F2,NA())` which should then be dragged to cover the next two columns and then down to cover every day.
- Selected A1:D11 (it'll be more than 11 on your version)
- Went to Insert > Chart > Insert Line or Area Chart > Line With Markers

At this point you have a line chart with three series (mo, mi, ev). The lines can be removed, which just leaves the markers. You can format each series separately, with different colours, shapes, sizes, etc.

As a special bonus, this automatically gives you a legend that explains the colours.

Comment: That's a pretty neat idea, thanks. I'll give it a bit before I lock it in as accepted and most helpful.

Comment: @Moreaki You're welcome - glad I could help.